# Is it possible to hide whether you're online in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is there a way to be on a server but the players can't see that you're online?

Comment: not on vanilla I believe

Comment: More details please! Is this your own server, that you can mod and have op on? Or are you wondering if there is any way to connect invisibly to any arbitrary server?

Comment: Considering his avatar, it might be that he wants to troll some servers.  If players cant know your online, it'd be perfect if you wanted to grief some building, and then when asked whether or not he/she was there, say "I wasn't online at the time"

Comment: "How do I manage to grief a server without being discovered?... *ahem*... not cause I am going to grief a server."

Comment: @Retrosaur I think you'll find that he said that he was the owner of this server, Unless he wants to troll his own server this is highly unlikely...

Comment: @user2104648 Where did he say this? I don't see this anywhere.

Comment: @Retrosaur It used to be in the title... but it's tagged "Hosting" now anyway.

Comment: I don't see any edits on this, so I have no clue what you're trying to say.  You obviously didn't write this question, so don't speak on his behalf

Comment: I'm voting to close as "unclear". The user's last seen datestamp is identical to when this was asked, so they've never even checked back to see if it got answered, let alone clarified what they were asking.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, via a [Bukkit](http://bukkit.org/) plugin called [Vanish No Packet](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/vanish/).

What the plugin does is it allows Server Operators defined by the Bukkit OP permission to type /v, or /vanish, doing so will toggle invisibility, and erase that player from the player list when someone presses TAB.

You can also configure it to stop invisible players from being able to break blocks, pick up items or talk.